# PaintComponent() not called despite setPreferredSize of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to understand why the following short piece code does not work.
I understand that when there are no Layout or the size of the component is 0, the paint component method isn't called.

But this isn't the case here.

Can you explain why I can't set the background for this?

```
public class Login extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage bgImage;

    public Login() {
        super();
        initImages();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        add(new JLabel("Hi"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void initImages() {
        try {
            bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File("images/login.jpg"));
            System.out.println("image loaded");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("image not loaded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println("repaint");
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Login login = new Login();
        frame.add(login, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `paintComponents` should be `paintComponent`

Comment: So I changed `paintComponents` to `paintComponent` and it works fine for me - Also, understand what `paintComponent` does, if you try painting before calling it's `super` method, anything your paint will be removed

Comment: oh wow so paintComponents is different to paintComponent .. 
So paint, paintComponents and paintComponent.. If you post your comment as an answer. I will select yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work, then you will need to change...

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
    System.out.println("repaint");
}
```

to something more like...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

`paintComponent` is responsible for painting the "bottom" layer of the component, `paintComponents` is responsible for painting the children

Comment: Thank you for your solution. After some research I found that loading the image inside the paintComponent method isn't ideal as this method is called repeatedly (and some times in quick succession), hence consumes resources unnecessarily. Is there a better approach for loading a background image?

Comment: What you're basically doing is the correct approach, loading it in the constructor